# В чём различие различных представлений числа?

Tags: математика, системы-счисления, binary

У меня есть некоторый файл. Написал программу, которая его считывает блоками по 16 бит. Вот вывод:

```
a5d0 b5d0 85d1 202c b7d0 b4d0 b0d0 80d1 
прочтено: 16
bed0 b2d0 b0d0 0a21 90d0 d020 d0b2 d1be 
прочтено: 16
2082 b8d0 d020 d0bf d0be d1b4 d08a d1b5 
прочтено: 16
d085 d0b0 d0bb 20b8 bad0 8bd1 80d1 b3d0 
прочтено: 16
8bd1 b7d0 8bd1 0a2e a1d0 bbd0 b0d0 b2d0 
прочтено: 16
b0d0 d020 d0a3 d1ba d080 d1b0 d097 d1bd 
прочтено: 16
2196 d020 d093 d1b5 d080 d1be d08f 20bc 
прочтено: 16
81d1 bbd0 b0d0 b2d0 b0d0 0a21 6f4c 6572 
прочтено: 16
```

Аналогичный кусок файла, только выводится по 32 бита.

```
прочтено: 32
b5d0a5d0 202c85d1 b4d0b7d0 80d1b0d0 b2d0bed0 0a21b0d0 d02090d0 d1bed0b2 
прочтено: 32
b8d02082 d0bfd020 d1b4d0be d1b5d08a d0b0d085 20b8d0bb 8bd1bad0 b3d080d1 
прочтено: 32
b7d08bd1 0a2e8bd1 bbd0a1d0 b2d0b0d0 d020b0d0 d1bad0a3 d1b0d080 d1bdd097 
прочтено: 32
d0202196 d1b5d093 d1bed080 20bcd08f bbd081d1 b2d0b0d0 0a21b0d0 65726f4c 
прочтено: 32
```

Видна некая симметрия между представлениями, но не могу выразить её строго математически - почему так?

Comment: Вас не смущает, что 2 * 16 == 32?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, так как ответ на него вряд ли может быть полезен кому-либо помимо автора вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Порядок_байтов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Дело в представлении числа. На моей машине используется little-endian.

Comment: Вы когда вопрос задавали как предполагали отвечающим догадываться, что такое "симметрия" и как именно вы "считываете блоками". Код программы бы показали - тогда еще можно было бы понять, что "блок" это разные типы данных и что под симметрией вы имеете ввиду задом наперед